# Rails 4 - Creating a folder inside public, to store uploaded files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

This is the sample in the documentation for Rails, when saving uploaded files.

```
def upload
  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end
```

This works alright, but what if I wanted to create a unique folder, for every upload made?

```
def upload

  // How to add this to the path of the saved file??
  uid = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)


  uploaded_io = params[:person][:picture]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end


end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create the directory if missing, then add it to `File.open`

```
dir = Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uid)
Dir.mkdir(dir) unless Dir.exist?(dir)
File.open(dir.join(uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(uploaded_io.read)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you consider to use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) or [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to upload your files? These gems are very easy to use.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ActiveRecord. I want to upload them, use them and delete them. Isn't Paperclip bad suited for that?

Comment: Actually I use carrierwave on my projects... are you managing these files on some model attributes? if yes, I really suggest these king of gems.. If not, I would suggest to create a model just to manage it (i.e. UploadFile model just with file:string attr)